# How do I pass real IP to Gunicorn when using Nginx and CloudFlare?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, cloudflare

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
http {

    ... <content removed for bevity> ...

    # Cloudflare
    set_real_ip_from   199.27.128.0/21;
    set_real_ip_from   173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   198.41.128.0/17;
    set_real_ip_from   162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from   104.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from   2400:cb00::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   2606:4700::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   2803:f800::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   2405:b500::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   2405:8100::/32;
    real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;

    upstream myproject {
        server unix:/var/www/myproject/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {

        listen XXX;
        server_name XXXXXX;

        ... <content removed for bevity> ...

        location / {
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://myproject;
        }

    }
```

Yet in Django the following code returns nothing to me:

```
request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '') # this gives me b''
```

How can I populate `REMOTE_ADDR` with the user's real IP address?

Note: When I remove the #Cloudflare section of the nginx configuration, `REMOTE_ADDR` is populated with Cloudflare's IP Address.

---

**Update**: I've added the following to my nginx configuration, however `request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')` is still empty.

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare append **X-Forwarded-For** and **X-Forwarded-Proto** headers. You can get and use X-Forwarded-For to logging customer's IP or to pass to another proxy or whatever you want.

Source: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170946-Does-CloudFlare-include-an-X-Forwarded-For-header-

Comment: Is there anyway I can populate the `REMOTE_ADDR` with X-Forwarded-For? I've tried `proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` and it doesn't seem to work.